# How would I disable the minimap in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

How would I get rid of the minimap in Xcode?

[image: screenshot of the minimap feature]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**in XCode 12.0.1**

there are 3 ways to hide or show `Minimap`.
first, you can do it with the `Adjust editor option` (see the following image).

[image]

next way: check or uncheck `Minimap` from Editor(menu) -> Minimap. (like following image)

[image]

and the last way you can use `⌃⇧⌘M` and show or hide Minimap.

Comment: This is the only way I could disable the minimap in the assistant view

Answer (score 84):

**Updated for Xcode 13**

Open a code file, such as `*.swift`, and press the second from the right button in the top right corner. Then click on *Minimap*:

[image]

In older versions of Xcode, this looked as follows:

[image]

Comment: I believe the screenshot in your answer is from an earlier beta (also, the feature has a keyboard shortcut now, [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57255509/3151675) for details)

Comment: Ah indeed, that's why I asked for your Xcode version. Guess it's time to update again... 

Comment: That seems to turn it off file by file (or at least column by column). Is there a global setting somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

Navigate to Adjust Editor Options (at the top right corner, to the left of the Add Editor Below button) and uncheck Minimap (or press <kbd>^⇧⌘M</kbd>).

[image: Screenshot of the Adjust Editor Options contextual menu]

Comment: This is the latest beta (beta 4), running on macOS 10.15 beta 4.

Comment: i;'m on 11 beta 3

Comment: @AntonTropashko Why would you be using an out-of-date beta? It's really important to always be using the most up-to-date beta. Beta 5 will probably be out in the next 48 hours.

Comment: it's the game you always lose

Answer (score 4):

This is called `minimap` window which give you insight of where you're in part of whole storyboard/code. This feature was introduced in Xcode11 and is quite useful.

You can show/hide simply by using shortcut key as: `cmd + shift + ctrl + M`.

Alternatively, you can choose '`Adjust Editor Options`' i.e multi-lined stacked icon present on top right of Xcode. `Deselect Minimap from dropdown list to hide it` and `Select to show it`.

[image: Screenshot]